# What does this paragraph in the ps man page mean?

Tags: unix, ps

I could not understand the following description:

```
   a               Lift the BSD-style "only yourself" restriction, which is
                   imposed upon the set of all processes when some BSD-style
                   (without "-") options are used or when the ps personality
                   setting is BSD-like. The set of processes selected in this
                   manner is in addition to the set of processes selected by
                   other means. An alternate description is that this option
                   causes ps to list all processes with a terminal (tty), or
                   to list all processes when used together with the x
                   option.
```

Only thing I could understand is the *An alternate description is xxxx*.  What does *Lift the BSD-style "only yourself" restriction* and other sentences mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the BSD version of `ps` (and, by extension, Linux's `ps` when it is treated as a BSD `ps` by passing it BSD-style options or by setting the `PS_PERSONALITY` or `CMD_ENV` environment variable to `bsd`) lists only the processes owned by the user running `ps`.

The `a` argument lifts that restriction and will show processes regardless of their owner.